# In depth technical interview on a subject of my choice

Tags: interviewing

I'm looking for advice for a particular upcoming interview. I've been told that I will have an interview where the interviewer goes deep on a technical subject of my choice.

The majority of my work experience has been in building web applications, and I'm unsure of how to proceed with this interview. I feel like I'm really a generalist and am suffering imposter syndrome about how much detail I know.

I am looking for suggestions on how to approach and prepare for this type of interview.

Answer (score 1):

I actually know the pain of this well, as I too am a generalist. Or, more precisely, a serial expert.  For any given project, I will focus on the technology stack I need to achieve the desired outcomes.  This tends to place me as an expert in one particular topic at any point in time.

So as a generalist who is mostly working in web development, which technology stack are you the most proficient in *at this point in time*?  Choose this one as the logical option.

*However*, don't be afraid to mention that you ARE a generalist, as we tend to be the most adaptable to changing technologies.  They are asking YOU what technologies that you are proficient in, not dictating what you SHOULD know :)

Comment: I guess the other thing is that I don't know what they mean by 'going deep' - in the case of web development I'm imagining they might go all the way from DNS and TCP through to the browser and Javascript and then back to databases etc. I'm not sure how to prepare!

Comment: Normally they mean go deep in a particular language, such as Java, MVC, and so on.  Understanding the language construct very well.

Comment: Is being a generalist an accepted IT term? I ask because I'm in the same boat with front/back end web design and that's a really perfect way to describe what I do as well.

Comment: @zfrisch The term "specialist" is well established. If you say "I am a Java web development specialist" then that will probably at least give someone a kind of expectation in their mind. However if you just say "I am a generalist." then you probably need to add some more explanation. Otherwise they might just think that you don't know any particular technology well enough, which is not the right impression. To me a "generalist" is a mindset of being open to new technologies and having the ability to learn them quickly. However you still need some speciality knowledge to do this.

Comment: @Brandin That's a good point. It's not as though I want to imply I have no specialization. I just have a variety of specialization in a lot of fields. More than a "Jack of All Trades" but less than someone who's focused on only one scope of knowledge. I think the key thing that's hard to convey is that I'm gifted at learning and picking up technical skills as needed to resolve an issue or complete a project. Is there a concise way to say that?

Comment: @Brandin Well said :)  If you didn't have the specialty knowledge, you wouldn't get hired in the first place :)